# Updating dragulaModel data in ng2-dragula - newly added array item is not reflected in list

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

I have the following ul list implementing dragula:

`<ul [dragula]="parent + '-bag'" [dragulaOptions]="getDragOps(parent)" [dragulaModel]="_treeService.tree">`

This is working well, and changes made through re-ordering the list are reflected back to the `_treeService.tree` array. However, if I add an element to this array from another component, it doesn't appear in the list (even though it has definitely been added to the array).

I guess I'm missing something here, but I thought `[dragulaOptions]` was supposed to sync changes automatically, including new items? I've read through the docs, both the [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) and the [original](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#drakeon-events) but I can't find the relevant method. What do I need to do to get it to reflect the updated array in the list?

Comment: @Ingo Have you able to find a solution for this. I am also stuck with the same issue. And not able to trace the cause

Comment: Hi, I guess you're the same guy who asked this on the github thread. Please see my comment there: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/804#issuecomment-358862952